# How to render ListView(as Row) inside ListView(as Column)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to render list of 6 teams.
Each team has five players, and design is that we have something like this

team 1 (column)
team 1 name (row)
team1-player1, team1-player2, team1-player3, team1-player4, team1-player5 (row),

team 2 (column)
team 2 name (row)
team2-player1, team2-player2, team2-player3, team2-player4, team2-player5 (row),

etc etc.

My app looks like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: renderTeams(teams),
  ),
);
```

and renderTeams looks like  this

```
Widget renderTeams(List teams) {
  return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: teams.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(teams[index]['name']),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: teams[index]['players'].length,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, playerIndex) {
              return PlayerCard(
                  player: teams[index]['players'][playerIndex]);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

}

With this setup i have 6 rows instead of 2. Each player has it's own row, or takes full width of the row. I'm not sure. I've tried adding second ListView.builder inside Row, but no luck. Some box constrains errors i am unable to fix.

And yes, PlayerCard's build

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Image.network(
        player['photo'],
        width: 100,
        height: 150,
      ),
      Text(player['name']),
      Text(player['nick']),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide some sort of graphics to show what you want? Simple neat drawing will do just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` widget has a `scrollDirection` property which indicates the axis on which the list entries are laid out. The default is `Axis.vertical` which is why your inner `ListView` lays the `PlayerCard` widgets vertically.

If you want all the `PlayerCard` widgets to fit within the screen's width, then the inner `ListView` should be replaced with a `Row`, and each `PlayerCard` should be wrapped with `Flexible` or `Expanded` to make them equal width within the `Row`.

If instead you want to scroll horizontally through a team's `PlayerCard` widgets, simply change the `scrollDirection` to `Axis.horizontal` and remove the `physics` property to let it scroll normally. You will likely want to wrap the `ListView` itself with `Expanded` so that it doesn't overflow from the `Column`.

Comment: Hey @Ovidiu, thanks for your response, it helped me :)

I managed to achieve desired behavior by removing inner ListView, adding Row, and adding PlayerCard wrapper with a Flexible Widget.